# What parameter(s) do I have to pass `gsutil` to access a Google Cloud local storage? (storage-testbench)

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gcloud

For test purposes, I want to run the [storage-testbench](https://github.com/googleapis/storage-testbench) simulator. It allows me to send REST commands to a local server which is supposed to work like a Google Cloud Storage facility.

In my tests, I want to copy 3 files from my local hard drive to that local GCS-like storage facility using `gsutil cp ...`. I found out that in order to connect to that specific server, I need additional options on the command line as follow:

```
gsutil \
  -o "Credentials:gs_json_host=127.0.0.1" \
  -o "Credentials:gs_json_port=9000" \
  -o "Boto:https_validate_certificates=False" \
    cp -p test my-file.ext gs://bucket-name/my-file.ext
```

See [.boto](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/boto-gsutil) for details on defining the credentials.

Unfortunately, I get this error:

> CommandException: No URLs matched: test

The name at the end (`test`) is the project identifier (`-p test`). There is an example in the [README.md of the storage-testbench project](https://github.com/googleapis/storage-testbench), although it's just a variable in a URI.

How do I make the `cp` command work?

**Note:**

The `gunicorn` process shows that the first `GET` from the `cp` command works as expected. It returns a 200. So the issue seems to be inside `gsutil`. Also, I'm able to create the bucket just fine:

```
gsutil \
  -o "Credentials:gs_json_host=127.0.0.1" \
  -o "Credentials:gs_json_port=9000" \
  -o "Boto:https_validate_certificates=False" \
    mb -p test gs://bucket-name
```

Trying the `mb` a second time gives me a 509 as expected.

---

More links:

- [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/GlobalCommandLineOptions) global options
- [gsutil cp ...](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp)

Comment: I've not used storage-testbench. `gsutil cp` doesn't support the Project (`-p`) flag as it's redundant. Buckets are owned by Projects but exist in a global namespace that doesn't require the Project to be specified when a(n existing) Bucket is referenced. The same error would result from the same command against the production service.

Comment: Oh! Wow! I found a post mentioning the `-p` flag and that's why I added it, but I also had other issues. It works without the `-p`! Darn... Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. `gsutil` is the quirky old uncle of Google's CLIs ;-)

Comment: Please post this as an answer as this would be very helpful to the members of the community with similar questions. Thank you.